# Reading the Stack Overflow RSS feed

Tags: c#, xml, feed, xmldocument, xmlreader

I'm trying to get a list of unanswered questions from [the feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/), but I am having trouble reading it.

```
const string RECENT_QUESTIONS = "https://stackoverflow.com/feeds";

XmlTextReader reader;
XmlDocument doc;

// Load the feed in
reader = new XmlTextReader(RECENT_QUESTIONS);
//reader.MoveToContent();

// Add the feed to the document
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);

// Get the <feed> element
XmlNodeList feed = doc.GetElementsByTagName("feed");

// Loop through each item under feed and add to entries
IEnumerator ienum = feed.GetEnumerator();
List<XmlNode> entries = new List<XmlNode>();
while (ienum.MoveNext())
{
    XmlNode node = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
    if (node.Name == "entry")
    {
        entries.Add(node);
    }
}

// Send entries to the data grid control
question_list.DataSource = entries.ToArray();
```

I hate to post such a "please fix the code" question, but I'm really stuck. I've tried several tutorials (some giving compile errors) but to no help. I assume I'm going the right way using an `XmlReader` and an `XmlDocument` as that's been a common thing from each guide.

Comment: Can you say what errors you are getting and what it is doing incorrectly?

Comment: You might consider using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx
instead.

Comment: @Simucal: It's just not providing any data, no errors as such.
@Brian: I looked at that and thought it was for creating feeds only. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your enumerator `ienum` contains only element, the `<feed>` element.  Nothing gets added to `entries` since this node's name is not `entry`.

I'm guessing you want to iterate over the child nodes of the `<feed>` element instead.  Try the following:

```
const string RECENT_QUESTIONS = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds";

XmlTextReader reader;
XmlDocument doc;

// Load the feed in
reader = new XmlTextReader(RECENT_QUESTIONS);
//reader.MoveToContent();

// Add the feed to the document
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);

// Get the <feed> element.
XmlNodeList feed = doc.GetElementsByTagName("feed");
XmlNode feedNode = feed.Item(0);

// Get the child nodes of the <feed> element.
XmlNodeList childNodes = feedNode.ChildNodes;
IEnumerator ienum = childNodes.GetEnumerator();

List<XmlNode> entries = new List<XmlNode>();

// Iterate over the child nodes.
while (ienum.MoveNext())
{
    XmlNode node = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
    if (node.Name == "entry")
    {
        entries.Add(node);
    }
}

// Send entries to the data grid control
question_list.DataSource = entries.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, this has really helped me to understand how to iterate through XML nodes now!